# If $p$ is a prime, and $2p = 2 \mod 4$ then $p = 3 mod 4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $p$ is a prime number, and $2p = 2 \mod 4$ then $p = 3\mod 4$

Is this true? I know that of the form $2x = 2\mod4$ then my solution must by of the form $2k+1$ or $1,3 \mod 4$ but does making p prime limit my solutions?

Comment: No, the statement is not true. For example, $p=13$. The condition $2p=2\mod 4$ only tells you that $p$ is an odd prime, so it can be $1\mod 4$ or $3\mod 4$.

Comment: No, because there are odd primes of both forms.

Comment: $2p\equiv 2\pmod 4\iff p\equiv 1\pmod{2}\iff p\equiv 1,3\pmod{4}\ \ $

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$p = 5$ is a counterexample. Actually, $2x \equiv 2\pmod4$ is true for any odd number $x$. So any prime congruent to $1$ modulo $4$ is going to be a counterexample. $13, 17, 29, 37$ and $41$ are all the other counterexamples below $50$.

Now, there are *slightly* more primes of the form $4k+3$ than there are of the form $4k+1$. This phenomenon is known as *Chebychev's bias*. But the difference is nowhere near enough to stop us from finding counterexamples.